# Add %20 between terms returned from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database of 2 word names and they have a space between them however in order for my api call to work I need a %20 between the first and second word.

Currently mysql_query returns Anas platyrhynchos and I need it to return Anas%20platyrhynchos

any quick solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php). That should solve your problem.

Comment: this is what i'm currently doing...
$search=urlencode(trim($_POST['searchterm']));

Comment: You need to urlencode the output from mysql, not the input from user.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [replace()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function to return the correct string from your query

```
replace(columnname,' ','%20')
```

Alternatively you can use the [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function to do this in your PHP code

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on the PHP side using `urlencode`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the returned result from the database. This will add %20 and other special URL characters I am assuming you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function.

```
Select Replace(colName, ' ', '%20')
```